# parse string like "now-1h" in R

Tags: r

what about experience by parsing/converting strings like "now-1h", "today", "now-3d", "today+30m" in R?
how to recognize and convert string (for example as function's argument) to date_time?

Comment: What is the set of possible "words" (like "today", "now"... is there also "yesterday", "tomorrow", other exotic values?). What is the source of such data?

Comment: we use PDB with time-stamp like "2017-03-17-08.32.20". Old perl-tools make possible select ranges as r1="2017-03-17,2017-03-18", r2="-3d,today", r3="now-2h,now". The reason is easy to ask, what is happens at the last hour, what happens last 3 days etc. It will be enough keywords "now", "today", "(d|h|m|s)"

Comment: to parse date-time "2017-03-17-08.32.20" make easy stringr or lubridate. But not easy for me use "2017-03-17,now"

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to preprocess your data with Perl then, to output more "standard" timestamps?

Comment: it works. but you need install libraries, development environment etc and depend from OS. I would like make it only with R

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, could you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply because of my business trip. I didn't have enough time to test completely. This idea is good, but it does not solve all problems. I'm hoping to find an one elegant solution. I believe in the R-power :). I'll try another try at the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I do **not** recommend using this code, which is brittle. This is just to demonstrate this is *possible*:

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

data <- c("now-1h", "today", "now-3d", "today+30m", "-3d")
```

We're going to use lubridate functions `now()`, `today()`, `days()`, `hours()`, ... which resemble your input data:

```
str(now())
#  POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-03-24 12:26:18"
str(today())
#  Date[1:1], format: "2017-03-24"
str(now() - days(3))
#  POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-03-21 12:27:11"
str(- days(3))
# Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
#   ..@ .Data : num 0
#   ..@ year  : num 0
#   ..@ month : num 0
#   ..@ day   : num -3
#   ..@ hour  : num 0
#   ..@ minute: num 0
```

We're going to have to `parse()` them as strings, to be able to actually use them, like that:

```
eval(parse(text = "now() + days(3)"))
# [1] "2017-03-27 12:41:34 CEST"
```

Now let's parse the input strings with a regex, manipulate them a bit to match `lubridate` syntax, then `eval()`uate them:

```
res <-
  str_match(data, "(today|now)?([+-])?(\\d+)?([dhms])?")[, - 1] %>% 
  apply(1, function(x) {
    time_ <- if (is.na(x[1])) NULL else paste0(x[1], "()")
    offset_ <- if (any(is.na(x[2:4]))) NULL else paste(x[2],
                                                       recode(x[4], "d" = "days(", "h" = "hours(", "m" = "minutes(", "s" = "seconds("),
                                                       x[3],
                                                       ")")
    parse(text = paste(time_, offset_))
  }) %>% 
  lapply(eval)
```

Notice that you get a variety of classes as output (either `POSIXct` or `Date` or `lubridate::Period`):

```
invisible(lapply(res, function(x) { print(x) ; str(x) }))

# [1] "2017-03-24 11:57:52 CET"
#  POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-03-24 11:57:52"
# [1] "2017-03-24"
#  Date[1:1], format: "2017-03-24"
# [1] "2017-03-21 12:57:52 CET"
#  POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-03-21 12:57:52"
# [1] "2017-03-24 00:30:00 UTC"
#  POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2017-03-24 00:30:00"
# [1] "-3d 0H 0M 0S"
# Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
#   ..@ .Data : num 0
#   ..@ year  : num 0
#   ..@ month : num 0
#   ..@ day   : num -3
#   ..@ hour  : num 0
#   ..@ minute: num 0
```

(What I recommend instead is to pre-process the data with the language that produced it and possesses the right tools for the job, which appears to be Perl).